# Is it possible to use <hue-interpolation-method> with animations or transitions?

Tags: css, colors, css-animations, css-transitions

Is it possible to specify a [<hue-interpolation-method>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/hue-interpolation-method) for anything other than gradients; specifically: transitions or animations?

```css
.box {
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
}

.box.gradient {
  background: linear-gradient(90deg in hsl longer hue, red, blue);
}

.box.transition {
  background: red;
  transition: 1s all;
}
  .box.transition:hover {
    background: blue;
  }
  
.box.animation {
  animation-name: color;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes color {
  0% {
    background: red;
  }
  100% {
    background: blue;
  }
}
```

```html
Linear-gradient using hue interpolation:
<div class="box gradient"></div>
<br><br>
Transition (hover) -- how do I get it to use the hue interpolation?
<div class="box transition"></div>
<br><br>
Animation -- how do I get it to use the hue interpolation?
<div class="box animation"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an active discussion to add a [`transition-interpolation`](https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/7063) property that should cover it, but it's not yet ready.

One other property that does use the`<hue-interpolation-method>` is the [`color-mix()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value/color-mix) function, which actually has even better browser support than in gradients.

However to animate this is not that easy.

One way is to define `@property` variables that we'll use as the percentage parameters of `color-mix` and animate the custom variables instead.

```css
@property --red {
  syntax: "<percentage>";
  inherits: false;
  initial-value: 100%;
}
@property --blue {
  syntax: "<percentage>";
  inherits: false;
  initial-value: 0%;
}
.box {
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
  --red: 100%;
  --blue: 0%;
  background: color-mix(in hsl longer hue, red var(--red), blue var(--blue));
  transition-duration: 2s;
  /* Do not set background-color here ! */
  transition-property: --red, --blue;
}
.box.transition:hover {
  --red: 0%;
  --blue: 100%;
}
.box.animation {
   animation: anim 2s infinite;
}

@keyframes anim {
  from {
    --red: 100%;
    --blue: 0%;
  }
  to {
    --red: 0%;
    --blue: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
transition<div class="box transition"></div>
animation<div class="box animation"></div>
```

For browsers that don't support the `@property` rule and thus animating custom variables (basically Gecko based browsers), you can create an animation with a lot of keyframes:

```js
const FPS = 60;
const duration = 2000;
const frames = FPS / (1000 / duration);
const keyframes = Array.from({ length: frames }, (_, i) => {
  const start = (i / frames) * 100;
  const end = 100 - start;
  return {
    background: `color-mix(in hsl longer hue, red ${end}%, blue ${start}%)`
  };
});
document.querySelector(".transition").addEventListener("mouseenter", (evt) => {
  const anim = evt.target.getAnimations()[0];
  if (anim) {
    anim.reverse();
  } else {
    evt.target.animate(
      keyframes,
      { duration, iterations: 1, fill: "forwards" }
    );
  }
});

document.querySelector(".transition").addEventListener("mouseout", (evt) => {
  const anim = evt.target.getAnimations()[0];
  if (anim) {
    anim.reverse();
  }
});

document.querySelector(".animation").animate(
  keyframes,
  { duration, iterations: Infinity }
);
```

```css
.box {
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
transition<div class="box transition"></div>
animation<div class="box animation"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

One hacky idea is to keep using the gradient and transition the position:

```css
.box {
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg in hsl longer hue, red, blue);
}

.box.transition {
  background-size: 10000% 100%; /* a very big width to see only colors and no transitions */
  background-position: left;
  transition: 1s all;
}

.box.transition:hover {
  background-position: right;
}

.box.animation {
  background-size: 10000% 100%;
  animation-name: color;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes color {
  0% {
    background-position: left;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: right;
  }
}
```

```html
Linear-gradient using hue interpolation:
<div class="box gradient"></div>
<br><br> Transition (hover) -- how do I get it to use the hue interpolation?
<div class="box transition"></div>
<br><br> Animation -- how do I get it to use the hue interpolation?
<div class="box animation"></div>
```

Comment: I've considered this. The limitation is that it only works for "background", and not other properties that accept color.. though there are hacks for those, too. Another consideration is if clipping of giant gradients is optimized or not, it. I'd really like confirmation of whether or not <hue-interpolation-method> is available to anything other than gradients.